# How to install Wordpress on subfolder (incl. wp-admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a domain, `www.example.com`, and I want to install Wordpress (4.7.4) to `www.example.com/wordpress/`. I'm also behind a nginx reverse-proxy, but not sure if that's relevant.

The following `.htaccess` does not work, ie. a `GET` request to `www.example.com/wordpress/` redirects to `www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php`. I need the entire install to live on `/wordpress/` subfolder, ie. `www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php`etc.

How can I configure this?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create "wordpress" directory in your domain root folder & then add .htaccess as mentioned below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for input. I actually ended up using a subdomain instead of subfolder, worked like a charm.

Comment: (y) Welcome! :)